# AngularJS ng-include finished

Tags: angularjs, templates

I'm loading a large amount of data using ng-include.

I'd like to know if there is a way to know when a template is "rendered", because sometimes it seems like it's been "frozen", because I want to do a "loading screen" or something.

Thx.

Here's the code

controller code:

```
$scope.layout = {
    current: 'single-table.html'
};

$scope.layout.get = function() {
    return $scope.layout.current;
};
```

templates:
main.html

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button ng-click="layout.current = 'single-table.html'">Single</button>
<button ng-click="layout.current = 'multiple-table.html'">Multiple</button>
</div>

<div ng-include="layout.get()"></div>
```

single-table.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{ column.title }}</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in records">
        <td ng-repeat="field in record.fields"
            ng-controller="FieldController"
            ng-class="getClass()">
            {{ field.display }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

multiple-table.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="record in records">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in record.fields">
        <th>{{ columns[$index].title }}</th>
        <td ng-controller="FieldController" ng-class="getClass()">
            {{ field.display }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT

I'm using version 1.2.0

One solution (probably not the best) is doing this (no ng-include)

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-show="layout.current == 'single-table.html'">
<thead>
    <th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{ column.title }}</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in records">
        <td ng-repeat="field in record.fields"
            ng-controller="FieldController"
            ng-class="getClass()">
            <span lud-run="{{ field.ng_directive }}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="record in records" ng-show="layout.current == 'multiple-table.html'">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in record.fields">
        <th>{{ columns[$index].title }}</th>
        <td ng-controller="FieldController" ng-class="getClass()">
            <span lud-run="{{ field.ng_directive }}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have only 20 records, but (is not in the code), each cells loads a custom directive depends on the data type (string, date, datetime, image...). This "solution" I think runs the same data twice (ng-show, not ng-if), but when a switch the layout mode there is no "lag".

Comment: What kind of data? Please provide more details and show use some code. What did you try?

Comment: Database rows. I have a button to switch the layout mode: one table per record or a table with multiple records.

Comment: Your loading screen should depend on the method populating `$scope.records` and not your `ng-include`. Please post your service and/or controller code fetching your data. You probably use `$resource` or `$http` and you can use a promise to achieve what you need

Comment: @apairet My problem is after retrieving the data. When I have the data loaded, if I switch the layout mode, it doesn't make any requests to the server (the data is already loaded), and it's taken a "long" time (1 or 2 seconds) and I can't put a "loading screen" because I don't know when the data is rendered.

Comment: OK, forget the answer I posted then. How many records do you have? If you have more than 200, say 500 or 2000, you might encounter `ng-repeat` performance issues.

Comment: What version of angular do you use? Do you need two-way data binding? If not, angular 1.3 introduces a one-time binding using the `::` prefix: `ng-repeat="record in ::records"` which will decrease your delay

Comment: I'm reading this: http://www.nodewiz.biz/angular-js-final-callback-after-ng-repeat/ I think I need something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onload` hook on `ng-include` to update a variable when the include has finished rendering. If you set it to true on clicking your button, then revert it back to false in `onload`, you should be able to leverage it to temporarily display a loading screen.